# javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: Unable to find a MessageBodyReader of content-type application/json and type class

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly

I am getting error when we upgarding `jboss as 7.1` to `wildfly 8.1`.

Following is my code where I got the error.

```
try {

    LOGGER.info("before authenticate {}");

    userTO = restEasyPortalServiceProxy.getLoginService().authenticate(userName, userPass);
    LOGGER.info("After authenticate : {}", userTO);
    userSessionData.setAuthToken(userTO.getAuthToken());

} catch (ResponseProcessingException responseProcessingException) {

    ExceptionMessage exceptionMessage = responseProcessingException
                                        .getResponse()
                                        .readEntity(ExceptionMessage.class);
```

My `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` is like same is working over `jboss as 7.1`

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- Exclude Version cxf of JBOSS -->
            <module name="org.apache.cxf" />
            <!-- Exclude JAVA EE of JBOSS (javax.ws..) => Add dependency javax.annotation -->
            <module name="javaee.api" />
            <!-- Exclude RestEasy conflict (javax.ws.rs.ext.RunDelegate) -->
            <module name="javax.ws.rs.api" />
            <module name="org.codehaus.jackson.jackson-core-asl" />
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-atom-provider" />
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-cdi" />
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-crypto" />
<!--        <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson-provider" /> --> 
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxb-provider" />
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs" />
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jettison-provider" />
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jsapi" />
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-json-p-provider" />
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-multipart-provider" />
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-validator-provider-11" />
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-yaml-provider" />
            <module name="org.codehaus.jackson.jackson-core-asl" />
            <module name="org.codehaus.jackson.jackson-jaxrs" />
            <module name="org.codehaus.jackson.jackson-mapper-asl" />
            <module name="org.codehaus.jackson.jackson-xc" />
            <module name="org.codehaus.jettison" />
            <module name="javax.ws.rs.api" />
        </exclusions>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson-provider" services="import"/>
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
```

Comment: Did you check the [similar question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12175564/unable-to-find-a-messagebodyreader-of-content-type-application-json-and-type-cla)

Comment: yes i have added  jackson-provider dependecies but getting same problem ,however same is working fine in jboss as 7.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this issue by adding org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jackson.ResteasyJacksonProvider in META-INF/services/javax.ws.rs.ext.Providers file .